# How do I change the generic folder icon in Yosemite 10.10.4?

Tags: macos, folders, icon, customization

I'm running 10.10.4, and can't seem to be able to change the generic folder icon. I've tried going into
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/ replacing the icon there but it made no change. Then I tried the app Liteicon and it just made the generic folder icon disappear. Does anyone know how to change it?

Comment: Reboot your Mac and Generic icon should re-appear

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Mac OSX Yosemite latest 10.10.5 and I've definitely sticked to the [CandyBar](http://download.panic.com/candybar/) app version 3.3.4 which is totally free from Panic inc.

I've been using **CandyBar** app since the Leopard days, the app works great until OS X 10.8 and "beyond", but now it is [free](https://www.panic.com/blog/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond) and unsupported, so for OS X Mavericks / Yosemite etc. it might work with some hiccups. Nevertheless one can change icons for almost everything from system files to folders.

Answer (score 0):

Litecon dosen't work with Yosemite 10.10.4 so I switched over to Folder Designer V1.1 from Fiplab in the Mac App Store its free

Comment: It unfortunately costs 3 bucks now but thanks for the suggestion. If I can't get another solution I guess yours is the best answer.

Comment: sorry it was free when I got it but it works wondefully and is very simple

Comment: Wait, so this app only changes a chosen folder's icon? Not the actual generic folder icon? Basically every time I make a new folder I'll have go into the app and change the icon?

Comment: only folders once changed they will stay as long as you like It does not change icons

Comment: Well my question is how to change the generic folder icon, so that OS X uses it as a default icon for a new folder and for all folders in general. Not how to change a specific folder, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must disable SIP.
Then you should clean the icon cache.(You can use Liteicon to do it.And you should disable SIP before you open the Liteicon)

Answer (score -1):

system integration protection (sip):

Good to stop viruses and malware, but bad for people who like to tinker. Remember to turn it back on and understand the risks of turning it off. They are important to know;

To turn off sip:

1. Restart mac
2. When restarting hold cmd+r
3. Select terminal
4. Type in "csrutil disable"
5. Click return
6. From the  menu select restart
7. To enable sip again repeat, but type in "csrutil enable" instead

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question as it is Yosemite, not El Capitan.

Comment: Yes, but it works in Yosemite and above. SIP was added in yosemite

Comment: SIP was added in El Capitan